# how to use callback or observable in angular2?

Tags: angular, callback, observable, angular2-services, asynccallback

I have work in angular2 project. but, one problem in our auth guard code.

I think script is not waiting result for callable function. then result variable console in "**undefined**".

Please show this console image. [image]

So, please help me.

**1) auth-guard.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
        export class RoutePermissionGuard implements CanActivate{
          private menuType:any;
          constructor(
            private router: Router,
            private _shared:SharedService
          ) { }

    // return only true or false
          canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):boolean {
            let url: string = state.url;
            let slug = route.data['slug'];
            let type = route.data['type'];
            if(slug !== ""){
              this._shared.menuList.subscribe(menus =>{
                  let result = this.getMenuOgj(menus,slug,type);
                  console.log("result: "+ result); // Get undefine varibale
              });
            }
            return true;
          }

    // This is recursive function and my first if condition is true then my second if is return true or false
          getMenuOgj(menus, menuSlug, type):boolean { // return only true or false
              menus.forEach((menu) =>{
                  if(menu.menu_slug === menuSlug){
                      if(type==="view"){
                          this.menuType = menu.view;
                      }else if(type==="edit"){
                          this.menuType = menu.edit;
                      }

                      if (this.menuType===1 || this.menuType==='1' || this.menuType===true) {
                          return true;
                      }else{
                          return false;
                      }
                  }
                  this.getMenuOgj(menu.submenu, menuSlug, type);
              });
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
getMenuOgj(menus, menuSlug, type) {
```

doesn't return anything.

```
return true;
```

only returns true from the callback passed to `menues.forEach(...)`

You need to return something at the and of `getMenuOgj()`

Comment: Please explain more what you tried or what you try to accomplish. I don't know what you expect to get returned.

Comment: "getMenuOgj" is recursive function and my first if condition is true then my second if is return true or false

Comment: Then just return `true` or `false` at the end of the function.